# What is the best approach to split an Arraylist based on their values

Tags: java

I would like to split an `ArrayList` that I am looping trough and set a field called `active` which can be `true` or `false`. But at the end of loop I would like to split this collection in two groups.. `active = false` and `active = true`, so doing this I won't need to search in database twice..

for example:

```
    private List<Classes> searchClasses(ClassItems listItems) {

    List<ClassItem> items = new ArrayList<ClassItem>();

    for (Iterator<ClassItem> iterator = listItems.getItems().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        ClassItems item = iterator.next();
        ClassEntityManager classEnt = ClassEntityManager.search(item.getId);

        if(classEnt.active()){
            item.setActive(true);
            items.add(item);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

What is the best approach to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make two lists instead of one.

```
if(classEnt.active()) {
    activeItems.add(item);
    item.setActive(true);
} else {
    inactiveItems.add(item);
}
```

Comment: OK, but i make this inside a method and i want to set this collection to an external list.. like: List<ClassItem> activeClasses = getActiveClasses or List<ClassItem> activeClasses = getInactiveItems but i dont wanna search twice in database

Comment: Well, there are several options. You can pass output lists into the method, like `private void searchClasses(ClassItems listItems, ClassItem activeItems, ClassItem inactiveItems)`, or you could make `activeItems` and `inactiveItems` members of the class (this is not a good option, I just mention it for completeness), or return a Map<Boolean,List<ClassItem>> from your method, or create a special "wrapper" class like `class ItemsResult { List<ClassItem> activeItems; List<ClassItem> inactiveItems }` and return that.

Answer (score 0):

Use two collections, one for actives and the other for not actives.

When you fetch the data from the DB, simply put the `CalssItem` in the correct list:

```
private List<ClassItem> searchClasses(ClassItems listItems) {

    List<ClassItem> activeItems= new ArrayList<ClassItem>();
    List<ClassItem> notActiveItems= new ArrayList<ClassItem>();

    Iterator<ClassItem> i = listItems.getItems().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) { //This is a better approach.
        ClassEntityManager classEnt = ClassEntityManager.search(i.next().getId);

        if(classEnt.active()){
            item.setActive(true);
            activeItems.add(item);
        }else{
            item.setActive(false);
            notActiveItems.add(item);
        }
    }
    List<ClassItem> ret = new ArrayList<ClassItem>(activeItems);
    ret.addAll(notActiveItems);
    return ret;
}
```

BUT, in this way, both `activeItems` and `notActiveItems` are unreacheable. Best thing to do is to have a loop **outside** your method that checks if the `ClassItem` is active or not. In this way both `activeItems` and `notActiveItems` can be deleted from the method:

```
private List<ClassItem> searchClasses(ClassItems listItems) {

    List<ClassItem> items= new ArrayList<ClassItem>();

    Iterator<ClassItem> i = listItems.getItems().iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) { //This is a better approach.
        ClassEntityManager classEnt = ClassEntityManager.search(i.next().getId);

        item.setActive(classEnt.active());

        items.add(item);
    }

    return items;
}
```

And to use the list:

```
List<ClassItem> items = searchClasses(classItems);
for(ClassItem item: items){
    if(item.isActive()){
        //do something
    }else{
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Better yet is to use the magnificient and beautiful Java 8 Stream API:

```
List<ClassItem> active = items.stream().filter(x->x.isActive).collect(Collectors.toList());

List<ClassItem> notActive = items.stream().filter(x->!x.isActive).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or the one liner:

```
List<ClassItem> active = searchClasses(classItems).stream().filter(x->x.isActive).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**NOTES**:

Your code has a return type of `List<Classes>`, while the returned value is of `List<ClassItem>`. Which is right?

Your iterator has a generic type of `ClassItem` while the `next()` method returns a `ClassItems` object. Which is right?

Comment: Ok Narmer, so the first method search into database and set true or false to active.. and if i want to get only active classes, i take another method that loop through and return that collection, and to inactive either.. right? thanks

Comment: Well, you don't strictly need another method. Best thing to do is to add items with `active` true or false in `searchClasses` method and use the returned list to loop trhough whenever you need it.